# Web scraping return one valor for page

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping

I would like the code to return all the products on the page, but it only returns the first product of each page. When I refer to a product, I mean (titles, names, descriptions, and prices). Please observe the code below:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import Workbook

```
            # Lista de URLs
            urls = [
                "/especies-de-plantas/mudas-de-plantas/plantas-ornamentais",
                "/especies-de-plantas/sementes-de-plantas",
                "/solucoes-paisagisticas/solucoes-cerca-viva",
                "/especies-de-plantas/mudas-de-plantas/paisagismo-com-bambu",
                "/especies-de-plantas/mudas-de-plantas/frutiferas",
                "/especies-de-plantas/mudas-de-plantas/especies-nativas",
                "/especies-de-plantas/livros",
                "/especies-de-plantas/mudas-de-plantas/frutiferas",
                "/vasos-e-mais.html",
                "/especies-de-plantas/mudas-de-plantas/suculentas",
                "/especies-de-plantas/adubos",
                "/especies-de-plantas/mudas-de-plantas/temperos",
                "/mais-para-o-jardim"
            ]

            wb = Workbook()
            sheet = wb.active
            sheet.append(["Categoria", "Nome", "Descrição", "Preço"])

            # Percorre as URLs
            for url in urls:
                full_url = f"https://www.sitiodamata.com.br{url}"
                response = requests.get(full_url)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

                # Verifica se é a seção de soluções paisagísticas
                if "/especies-de-plantas/mudas-de-plantas/plantas-ornamentais" in url:
                    page = 1
                    while True:
                        page_url = f"{full_url}?p={page}"
                        page_response = requests.get(page_url)
                        page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, 'html.parser')

                        titulos = page_soup.find_all(class_='category-description')
                        nomes = page_soup.find_all(class_='product-item-name')
                        descricoes = page_soup.find_all(class_='descricao-item')
                        precos = page_soup.find_all(class_='price-wrapper precos-estoque-cor preco-size ')

                        for titulo, nome, descricao, preco in zip(titulos, nomes, descricoes, precos):
                            titulo_solucoes = titulo.text.strip()
                            nome_solucoes = nome.text.strip()
                            descricao_solucoes = descricao.text.strip()
                            preco_solucoes = preco.text.strip()
                            sheet.append([titulo_solucoes, nome_solucoes, descricao_solucoes, preco_solucoes])

                        if page < 25:
                            page += 1
                        else:
                            break

            # Salva a planilha como um arquivo Excel
            wb.save("dados_sitiodamata_categoria1.xlsx")
```

I am unable to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you will print length of titulos variable than you can see it's 1. There is 1 Category Description, if you put titulos variable out of the loop it will be work. Like this:

```
titulo_solucoes = titulos.text.strip()

    for nome, descricao, preco in zip(nomes, descricoes, precos):
            nome_solucoes = nome.text.strip()
            descricao_solucoes = descricao.text.strip()
            preco_solucoes = preco.text.strip()

            print(titulo_solucoes)
            print(nome_solucoes)
            print("********")
```